# PHP File Download with Query String

Tags: php, file, download

I am curious how I could make a PHP script where you pass your username and password to my webserver and it downloads a file (or multiple) that is specific to that one user only. I am not sure where to start. Could someone please help? thanks!

Comment: Do you have a database with users, files and a table that connects the two?

Comment: Yes I have a mysql database where users and passwords are saved. I know how to access it and everything already so I do not need help with that. Just with the actual downloading of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

You shouldn't put a password directly in the URL. Instead, use a random generated token, for example using MD5 (`$token = md5($username.time());`). So, your user table should look like this :

```
id
email
password
token
```

The URLs you'll provide to your user will be like this :

```
http://www.example.com/download.php?token=$userToken&file=$file
```

And download.php:

```
<?php
if ( ! isset($_GET['token']) || ! isset($_GET['file'])) {
    //throw 404
}
//check token exists in DB else throw 403
//use readfile function :)
```

Comment: Do you need more info? From your comment you said that you only needed to know how to force download. This links explains everything :)

Comment: Thank you for that link. I can't read french though but I opened it in English as well. The problem with that method though is I think I may create a program to download the file for the users as well, I was thinking of like an updater for a program/game I create and I don't think that would work well for my purposes.

Comment: Oops, sorry for the link in french, I didn't paid attention to that!

Answer (score 0):

First you could create a mysql table for all users. Then you could make a second one where the filenames and usernames are saved like "file:test.png user:xyz" that every file has an owner. If somebody wants to download a file you have to check if this user is the file owner in the database. The list of all files then shows all files of this user.

Comment: I already have the database done, but I am not sure how to do the downloading part. I want it where I can allow the users to download the file(s) from the site as well as possibly for an auto updater as well or some other implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example:

```
download.php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['user_info']) && check_validity($_GET['user_info'])) {
  $file_info = determine_file_info($_GET['user_info']);
  header("Content-type: " . $file_info['type']);
  header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_info['name'] . '"');
  readfile($file_info['absolute_path']);
  exit;
}
?>
```

That mock-up imagines you have defined a function `check_validity` that determines if the given user info is valid, and that you have defined a function `determine_file_info` that uses the user info to build an array of file type, file name, and file path (where the file is on the server).